# Authentication accessing ActiveDirectory with DirectorySearcher

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I need to access information in my Active Directory domain using domain credentials.
The DirectorySearcher class does not have user and password arguments.
How can I specify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "Authenticating to your Directory" section from [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx). The gist of it is you connect to your ldap root with DirectoryEntry (That takes credentials in the constructor) and then use a DirectorySearcher on it.